# How to upload SQL Server CE Db to SkyDrive for windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

Say I have an app that uses SQL Server CE database in windows phone. How do I upload this SQL Server CE database (`.sdf` file) to SkyDrive? The SQL Server CE database is in isolated storage. What are the steps I need to do to upload it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shelly_guos_ms_blog/archive/2011/09/20/get-started-on-live-sdk-for-windows-phone.aspx) for SkyDrive and the [samples](https://github.com/liveservices/livesdk)?

[more](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_live/b/windowslive/archive/2011/07/20/developers-learn-how-to-bring-data-from-hotmail-messenger-and-skydrive-to-your-mobile-apps.aspx)

Comment: base on SkyDrive Documentation. It supports only :1) Documents (Portable Document Format (PDF) files, text files, and Microsoft Office files)
2) Photos (common image file formats)
3) Videos (H.264 and Windows Media Video (.wmv))
4) Audio (downloading any audio file type, and uploading Waveform Audio File Format (.wav) only, is supported) . I think I needed another solution.

Comment: Yeah, I see that, you could always turn fiddler on, upload a random file and duplicated the calls.

Comment: Sound good, how to do that on wp7. I think this could help my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Access to Sky Drive is part of Live Connect.
This is being shipped with the Windows 8 SDK and contains examples for access from Windows Phone.
As such it looks as if you will need to download the Windows 8 Developer Preview.
Full details start here http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_live/b/windowslive/archive/2011/12/07/skydrive-apis-for-docs-and-photos-now-ready-to-cloud-enable-apps-on-windows-8-windows-phone-and-more.aspx

Comment: There is an API that can be used without having to I stall w8.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with a SQLite database file following the tutorial [here](http://nikovrdoljak.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/backup-your-windows-phone-isolated-storage-data-to-skydrive-using-live-connect-api/). I changed the upload filename to a `.txt` extension. It's a kludge, but it worked. If the Live API isn't going to allow other file types, then ideally I'd like to be able to change the filename after upload, but I haven't found a way to do this yet.